# Секретные шляпы для всех, даром, и пусть никто не уйдёт обиженный!

Tags: поддержка, новогодние-шляпы

Как получить секретные шляпы WinterBash? Рассказываем!

Используйте спойлеры:

```
>! какой-то текст
```

Comment: @Abyx  Видел шляпу у Abyx . Красная и он одел в птичку свою. Кто знает что это? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177684/abyx

Comment: @Saidolim спросите у него в чате.

Answer (score 10):

**FLIP FLOP**

И от меня вам секретная шляпка

> Проголосовать ЗА за вопрос, опубликованный менее 5 минут назад

[image] [image]

Comment: Только что получил за этот вопрос: [python Ubuntu error install Pillow 3.0.0](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33404394)

Comment: Получил шапку синего цвета. Это тоже она?

Comment: @Saidolim а название такое же?

Comment: @Mira да тоже `Flip Flop`. Может по полу определяет?

Comment: Наверно так и есть %) сегодня уже много народу в этой шляпе

Comment: Похоже, шляпа давалась за голосование по любому вопросу.

Comment: По любому, условие - скорость %)

Answer (score 9):

## 007

> Три условия одновременно: нужно на вопрос с 0 комментариев дать ответ с 0 комментариев, и ответ должен набрать рейтинг +7. Удаленные комментарии всё равно считаются.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 7):

## Cleanup Crew

> Для этой шляпы нужно удалить 30 комментариев

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: собственных же?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, а это под вопросом. Возможно, не собственных тоже, но это уже модератор может проверить.

Comment: удалил, что-то не дают шапку.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, на складе закончилось, наверное.) Возможно, есть ещё какое-то неизвестное условие. Я начинал удалять с конца списка, отсортированного по возрасту комментариев (от младшего к старшему). Но мои самые старые комментарии имеют возраст не более 3-4 месяцев.

Comment: Тут пишут, что нужно около 50 удалить. [Winter Bash 2015 Secret Hats](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271029)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, не, я 50 не удалял. Может и сбился где-то со счёта, но на 20 промахнуться не мог. Скажем, не 30, а 35. У нас тут один в чате писал, что удалил 70 и ничего не получил.

Comment: Насчёт этой шляпы появилось подозрение, что дело не в 30 удалённых, а количестве голосов в удалённых комментариях. Среди тех, что я удалил, было много комментариев с голосами больше одного. Бывало и 3-4 тоже.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, удалил 30 комментов - получил шапку, список удаленных со статистикой можно посмотреть [здесь](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33208)

Comment: @Alex, забейте на это.

Answer (score 5):

## Hairboat's Revenge

У этой лодочки есть история, связанная с какими-то интригами и взаимными подколами на Meta SE. Но я вам ее не расскажу, потому что сам не понял. Идея вот в чем:

> Шляпа дается за любой комментарий под постом [Jon Ericson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1438/jon-ericson) (за всё, что создает нотификацию в его входящих сообщениях).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: оказыватеся под мета не дает. Сказано что   meta.SFF.SE, meta.SE, не входит в это. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270851/311807

Comment: @Saidolim: да, верно.

Answer (score 5):

## Odinson

Сын Одина — Тор, атрибут Тора — Молот. Так что понятно, что нужно *жахнуть*.

> Вы должны ударить «волшебным молотом» — то есть, «золотым» голосом за дубликат. Если у вас нету, вы должны хотя бы внести свой вклад в удар: проголосовать за закрытие перед тем, как золотой молот закроет вопрос окончательно.
>  («Золотой голос за дубликат» по какой-нибудь метке вы получаете, если у вас есть золотой бедж по этой метке.)

[image: Тор!]

Answer (score 5):

## Sun Wukong

> Пост на Мете, на котором не менее чем 5 голосов за и 5 голосов против.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поощрение читерства? С трудом себе представляю настолько неоднозначное сообщение, за которое будут активно голосовать

Comment: @tutankhamun: бывают, например в вопросе [Сбор вопросов для будущих кандидатов в модераторы сообщества 2015](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2028)

Answer (score 4):

## Amazing Grace

> Вопрос на Мете с меткой [дефект], имеющий рейтинг 10+, на который дан ответ с рейтингом 10+. Шляпа дается автору вопроса.

[image: Amazing Grace]