# Секретные шляпы 2018 года

Tags: обсуждение, новогодние-шляпы

Как было объявлено ранее, завершение 2018-го года ознаменовано началом сезона шляп: [Отпразднуем завершение 2018го года Сезоном шляп!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8383/189339) - а это значит, что помимо описанных для всех шляп, снова будут и секретные шляпы.

Несколько лет назад на мете возникал подобный вопрос, но время идет и шляпы меняются, предлагаю в качестве ответов публиковать секретные шляпы и за что они даются! Думаю, что многим будет интересно, возможно кто-то собирает шляпы!

> Шляпники, будьте дружнее!

Ссылка на вопрос 2015 года: [Секретные шляпы для всех, даром, и пусть никто не уйдёт обиженный!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2101/189339)

Ссылка на вопрос 2016 года: [Как узнать, за что дали секретные шляпы?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4287/189339)

> [Список лидирующих шляпников stackoverflow на русском](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/ru.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Что-то 2017 не видно)

Comment: @Qwertiy как-то не нашел, либо плохо искал :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Обсудить условия получения шляп на русском можно в [основном чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--) сообщества.

Ниже перевод [ответа с MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319838/winter-bash-2018-hat-list)

Редактируйте этот ответ только в случае **точного и корректного условия получения шляпы**. Это не место для гадания о условиях получения шляпы, используйте [чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86686/winter-bash-2018-edition) для обсуждения.

## Секретные шляпы Winter Bash 2018

Пожалуйста, помещайте описание условий получения под спойлер используя  `>!`. Чтобы увидеть условие, наведите на него мышкой или кликните/щёлкните по нему.

#### Retro Fan

[image: Retro Fan]

> [Проголосовать за пост (вопрос или ответ) опубликованный более чем 1 год назад](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86686/conversation/retro-fan)

---

#### The Merlin

[image: The Merlin]

> Получите знак [Просвещенный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/19/enlightened)

---

#### James Bond

[image: James Bond]

> 007: Опубликуйте ответ получивший как минимум +7 голосов с 0 комментариев к вопросу и 0 комментариев к ответу.

---

#### Waffles

[image: Waffles]

> Опубликуйте 15 комментариев к вопросу и/или его ответу

---

#### Rubber Ducky

[image: Rubber Ducky]

> Используйте кнопку "отменить" на странице "Задать вопрос".

---

#### Sun Wukong

[image: Sun Wukong]

> Опубликуйте пост на мета сайте (MSE также считается за мета сайт) который получит как минимум 5 голосов "за" и 5 голосов "против".

---

#### Clean-Up Duty

[image: Clean-Up Duty]

> [Исправьте 20 меток под вопросами]

---

#### Propel Thyself

[image: Propel Thyself]

> [Получите три другие секретные шляпы на одном сайте](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86686/conversation/propel-thyself-test)

---

#### Eliza Doolots

[image: Eliza Doolots]

> Заработайте +200 репутации на каждом из ваших лучших шести сайтов во время Winter Bash.

Предложено Catija [здесь](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304644/358161)

---

#### Примечания:

Это не место для гадания для условий срабатывания шляп. Используйте комментарии только с одной целью: улучшить ответ. Если вы хотите обсудить шляпы - используйте [специальный чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86686/winter-bash-2018-edition).

Comment: Тут вот только что новую шляпу обнаружили: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319840/219368. Сорри, недостаточно репы для правки.

Comment: Знаю, что перевод, но объясните мне, вот зачем, зачем на enMeta раскрывать порядок получения *секретных шляп* именно сейчас!? Можно было сделать это хотя бы за 3-5 дней до конца ивента((

Comment: Может кто знает как получить шляпку **Clean-Up Duty**? Пожалуйста, раскройте тайну!

Comment: @Bharata, там до сих пор точно не понятно за что дается эта шапка, но точно связана с редактированием (правки, теги, тревоги, ...) .

Comment: @Bharata, когда-то было 30 комментов удалить. Но не факт, что на эту шляпу, да и поменяться могло.

Comment: @Qwertiy, я уже узнал как - добавил в ответ,

Comment: Ой.. Неужели я ещё 20 раз метки не правил? о_О